# Ordering information from your database

Tags: php, mysql

Here is what I want to do: I want to have a script that grabs all of the images a user ever shared on my site, and display them in groups based on the month/date when they shared it.

Here is my table structure:

```
| user_id | post_date | story | image |
|-------------------------------------|
| 14      | mar 2012  | BLOB  | a.jpg |
| 14      | apr 2012  | BLOB  | b.jpg |
| 14      | feb 2012  | BLOB  | c.jpg |
| 14      | mar 2012  | BLOB  | d.jpg |
|_____________________________________|
```

So, I want the information retrieved based upon the user's id, then displayed in groups based upon date. I am clueless as where to start. The group names are the name of the month, so do I have to do a query to figure out how many different months a user shared a post in? And then how do I group the data? I am not expecting someone to code everything for me. I just am unsure of how to start. Thanks.

Comment: You're wanting to show all images ever collected, sorted by user and then by date?

Comment: I want to show all Images ever collected for a particular user, then sorted by date.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the query, it might solve all of your problems. If you want a good answer, please include an example of the result you want. Something like

```
Select image, post_date
Where user_id = @userId
Order By post_date Desc
```

Then read through the results, and when the month/year/whatever changes in the date returned, create a new "group".

Answer (score 1):

You can order them by post_date

```
select fields from mytable order by post_date
```

but you can't really have subgroups as below:

```
select fields from mytable group by year(post_date), month(post_date)
```